# How to union 3 regular expression?

Tags: regex

```
M/D/YY    /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2})$/           
M-D-YY    /^(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{2})$/
M.D.YY    /^(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2})\.(\d{2})$/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^(\d{1,2})([\/.-])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{2})$/
```

Watch out, now there is a new capturing group, so the year will be in backreference number 4 instead of 3 as before.

If you also want to allow `M/D-YY` etc., then you can use

```
/^(\d{1,2})[\/.-](\d{1,2})[\/.-](\d{2})$/
```

Comment: Tim, I took the liberty to place `-` at the end of the char-class.

Comment: The unescaped `.` in the separator group will match any character.

Comment: /^(\d{1,2})([-/.])(\d{1,2})([-/.])(\d{2})$/ I can check here http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: @Håvard - Not inside a character class.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to write:

```
(r1)|(r2)|(r3)
```

where the ri are the regular expressions you have. You can factor out common parts, of course, like the anchors, so

```
^(?:(r1)|(r2)|(r3))$
```

In fact, in your case the regexes differ only in the separator characters used, so you could put them in a character class to get a common regex.

Comment: In case of `^(r1)|(r2)|(r3)$`, only `r1` is anchored to the start of the string and `r3` to the end. You probably meant: `^(?:(r1)|(r2)|(r3))$`

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture the first separator and do a back-reference:

```
/^(\d{1,2})([\/-\.])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{2})$/
```